# How to find the number of integer clusters (efficiently) from a continuously running random integer generator?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

There is a random integer generator, which generates random integers and it is being run at background. There is a requirement to design an API which returns the number of clusters at that time when it is called.

Cluster: A cluster is a lexicographical order of continuous integers. e.g., 10,7,1,2,8,5,9 in this case clusters are 3 (1,2--5--7,8,9,10).

How to solve this problem when there are billions or trillions of integers. What could be an optimal solution? (Keep in mind that generator is being run in background and call to API can be made anytime and many times)

My Approach: Keep inserting integers from the generator into a list. When a call is made to API, sort (insertion) the list, and traverse through it to find the number of clusters. But I think this one is not an efficient way to do it.

Comment: What are the rules by which `2--5--6` became a cluster, but the other numbers are isolated?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some kind of interval tree. Not the standard one, which can track overlapping intervals, but a simpler one that tracks only disjoint intervals and automatically merges overlapping/adjacent intervals.

So a BST of intervals, sorted by start. To insert a new interval,

1. find the highest-less-than the start of the new interval and join it with it if they're adjacent
2. take the interval you now have (either the one you're inserting or the joined interval) and find the lowest-higher-than its end point, join them if adjacent.
3. if you've joined twice, remove the first (shorter) joined interval.
4. if you have joined zero times, insert the new interval as a new node
5. apply the usual BST balancing rotations if necessary to keep the tree at least somewhat balanced

The number of clusters is, at any time, the number of leaves. You don't even have to explicitly count them, just update the count as you change the tree.

Insert is logarithmic in the number of clusters, their size is irrelevant. That has the fun side effect that for random integers, this gets slower for a while as the tree keeps having to represent mostly unit intervals, but when enough integers are in there it slowly starts to get faster again, since beyond a certain point inserts would tend to join more intervals than they create. Eventually, with every integer in the tree, it would have just one node left, representing the single cluster spanning all integers.